# Create a circular View which impact inner views

Tags: android, xml

I have a parent view and in this view I have multiple textview. I want to create outer view circular and inner textviews should also impact this outer circular border.

[understanding the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzYkw.jpg)

when I circulate outer view It is not affecting inner view.

Comment: Have you tried setting clipToOutline on a parent view to true?

Comment: yes. I have tried this solution but it is not efficient. It create distortion after some time.